# How to specify icon in lower left corner

Tags: kubuntu, icons, appmenu

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04. There's an icon in the lower left corner that brings up the application list (by default a big K).  I did something that changed it, but I don't know what.  Where in the system settings is it specified?

Comment: The default Ubuntu icon is known as a Bento menu - 9 dots in a 3x3 grid. What version of Ubuntu are you using? Please [edit] your question rather than just add to the comment chain.

Comment: @24601, it seems like Paul is using Kubuntu, since the default icon for the "Kicker" menu is a "big K".

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: Sounds like your using the KDE desktop environment that icon is located here.

`$KDEDIR/share/icons/oxygen/scalable/places/start-here-branding.svg (usually /usr/share/....)`

If it is not located there or you are using a different desktop environment please post which distribution your using.

Comment: As I revised my question to say, I'm running Kubuntu 18.04. I'm looking for a way to set this icon via System Settings. It's great that KDE is so configurable, but it can be hard to find the setting you want.

Comment: It's also easy to change a setting unintentionally.

Comment: I have Kubuntu 18.04. I've revised the question to state that.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the icon, and pick "Application Launcher Settings."

Then click on the Icon button and select "Choose". Navigate to the icon you want and use that. It looks like this:

[image: See?]

The image looks a little funny because I used DistroTest to grab the screenshot. However, that's 18.04 and that's how you change the icon for the application launcher/menu.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to make changes with the K Menu Editor. If you can't find it, open Konsole and type `kmenuedit`

Comment: I tried using kmenuedit, but it called forth a deluge of cryptic messages, starting with "kf5.kcoreaddons.kaboutdata: Could not initialize the equivalent properties of Q*Application: no instance (yet) existing."

Comment: I got to the place where a huge array of icons is shown.  But oddly, not one of them has a big K.