# Where is the kicker icon?

Tags: kde, icons

I'm running Kubuntu 18.04. Where is the file for the kicker icon (the big K in the lower left corner of the applications menu)?

Comment: Do you mean the icon from [your question yesterday](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320034/how-to-specify-icon-in-lower-left-corner)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to specify icon in lower left corner](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1320034/how-to-specify-icon-in-lower-left-corner)